# Karma, empty test suite

Tags: testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

First of all I know there are similar questions, but none of it works for me.

I have an Angular app, and I would like to test it with Karma, Jasmin, and RequireJs.

I have installed everything I need, and configured everything as it is written here: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html

Below is how my files look like

### karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
      basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'src/test/Tests/*.js',
        'src/test/Tests/directives/*.js',

        //source code
        {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/app/*.js', included: false},
        {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/app/**/*.js', included: false},

        {pattern: 'src/test/test-main.js', included: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'test/Tests/*.js': 'coverage'
    },

      coverageReporter:{
          type:'html',
          dir:'../coverage/'
      },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
      reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

### test-main.js

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
var allTestFiles = [];

// Get a list of all the test files to include
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        // If you require sub-dependencies of test files to be loaded as-is (requiring file extension)
        // then do not normalize the paths
        var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
        allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
    }
});

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base',

    //dynamically load all test files
    deps: allTestFiles,

    // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

### The output is in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5

Empty test suite.

Process finished with exit code 0

---

The server starts correctly. I have also tried with command line. $ karma start, and $ karma run, which also does nothing. There is no error message at all. The path is correct, there is no 404 error.

Do you have any guess what could be the problem?

Comment: instead of using pattern, try including test-main.js directly

Comment: @Jagrut Thanks for the guess, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you create any Spec file with test cases?

Comment: @Jagrut I'm not calling them *Spec.js or *.spec.js, but *_test.js, and they are loaded and stored in  allTestFiles array, which is loaded by requireJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete the module names from test files.

In my case, this was the solution.

According to RequireJS documentation (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) you can include a name for the module as you can see below:

```
//Explicitly defines the "foo/title" module:
define("foo/title",
    ["my/cart", "my/inventory"],
    function(cart, inventory) {
        //Define foo/title object in here.
   }
);
```

But for me, Karma only executes the tests if I delete the *"foo/title"* name.